# ApplicationError: 10 using Google Cloud Storage Java API to read a big zip file

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm working on reading a zip file stored in a Google Cloud Storage bucket from a Google App Engine application, using the Google Cloud Storage Java API.
It's work fine for small files, but when I try to read the real file I need (25Mb compressed) I get a ApplicationError: 10 exception. The tests are done the application deployed on GAE.

I may have understand that ApplicationError: 10 is thrown when the file is opened for too long (+ than 30s) see : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-java/5XBVaVDKvvs, but I'm still struggling to get this thing work.

Thanks for your help.

There is the testing code I used :

```java
FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
AppEngineFile readableFile = new AppEngineFile("/gs/xxxx-my-bucket/xxx-bigfile.zip");
FileReadChannel readChannel = fileService.openReadChannel(readableFile, false);
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(Channels.newInputStream(readChannel));
ZipEntry ze = null;
while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    resp.getOutputStream().println("Unzipping " + ze.getName());
    for (int c = zis.read(); c != -1; c = zis.read()) {
        resp.getOutputStream().print((char) c);
    }
    zis.closeEntry();
} 
zis.close();
```

The stacktrace I get is :

```
java.io.IOException
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.translateException(FileServiceImpl.java:617)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.makeSyncCall(FileServiceImpl.java:590)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.read(FileServiceImpl.java:539)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.read(FileServiceImpl.java:410)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileReadChannelImpl.read(FileReadChannelImpl.java:73)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:109)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:103)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:186)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:238)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:163)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:122)
    at fr.heliorama.skylinewebapp.servlets.TestGSZip.doGet(TestGSZip.java:30)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:102)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:249)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:477)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 10: 
    at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1495)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.doSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:237)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.access$000(ApiProxyImpl.java:68)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:182)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:180)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:180)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:68)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:101)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.makeSyncCall(FileServiceImpl.java:586)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 10: 
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.failure(ApiProxyImpl.java:546)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher$1.runInContext(RpcStub.java:784)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.rpcFinished(RpcStub.java:824)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.failure(RpcStub.java:815)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.runCallbacks(RpcClientInternalContext.java:895)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.finishRpcAndNotifyApp(RpcClientInternalContext.java:798)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.afterFinishingActiveRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:1054)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.finishRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:902)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.handleResponse(RpcNetChannel.java:2250)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.messageReceived(RpcNetChannel.java:2057)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.access$2000(RpcNetChannel.java:143)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcNetChannel.java:3112)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcChannelTransportData$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcChannelTransportData.java:599)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcBaseTransport.receivedMessage(RpcBaseTransport.java:417)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcClientTcpTransport.parseOneMessage(RpcClientTcpTransport.java:750)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcClientTcpTransport.parseMessages(RpcClientTcpTransport.java:634)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcClientTcpTransport.access$100(RpcClientTcpTransport.java:37)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcClientTcpTransport$1.dataReceived(RpcClientTcpTransport.java:295)
    at com.google.net.async3.SocketConnection.handleNetworkReadEvent(SocketConnection.java:900)
    at com.google.net.async3.SocketConnection.access$400(SocketConnection.java:43)
    at com.google.net.async3.SocketConnection$NetworkReadHandlerImpl.run(SocketConnection.java:929)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask$Sync.innerRun(AbstractFutureTask.java:260)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask.run(AbstractFutureTask.java:121)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runTask(EventManagerImpl.java:575)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.internalRunWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:999)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:881)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.WorkerThreadInfo.runWorkerLoop(WorkerThreadInf...(length 8282)
```

Comment: I don't have any brilliant ideas, but perhaps you can try and just download the file to your local computer without unzipping it. You can then unzip the local copy. Perhaps that will get rid of the timing issue, if that is indeed the problem, or at least help you better identify what the problem actually is.

Comment: Is the file open for longer than 30 seconds?

Comment: @Howard : Good idea, I'm going to try the read the data unzipped, like a binary stream, we'll see what it does. BTW, the reader is on GAE, so  I cannot just download it to my local computer.

Comment: @Stuart : Yes, I think it is. At least the test I'm doing (output the zip content as a servlet result) crashs near 30s after starting.

Comment: So that explains the error then, right? You can only have the file open for 30 seconds or you will see an IOException.

Comment: I tried to just read the plain unzipped data, without doing anything with it, I got the same behavior.

Comment: @Stuart : Yes It does, unfortunately. I guest I'll have get it with multiple reads using offsets. Anyway, is not the purpose of GCS storing large files ? I'm getting to wonder if GAE is suited to my app : I need to access very large data (5Gb, read only, never modified - it's Digital Elevation Model of Europe) do some computation on some part of it and serve small responds to the end user. The datastore does not seems to fit, GS looked nice at the time.

Comment: You can store large files in GCS or the AppEngine blobstore. Without understanding your access patterns it's hard to advise the best way for you to work around the 30 second limit. In your example code your trying to unzip the entire file and it's not clear to me why you' want to do that with a 5GB file in the first place.

Comment: Thank your for your interest in my situation. It may be a little out of the scope of this topic but I will try to explain my user case. The data a want to store and access this Digital Elevation Model : It's roughly a data matrix that store the elevation of places by latitude / longitude. All the data is organized in tiles corresponding to all places within one degree of latitude and one degree of longitude, each tile is zipped. The size of the tiles is few kB to 25MB. I'm not in charge of the DEM, so I prefer not to modify it's internal data storage organization.

Comment: The access pattern of my app is the following : for one particular place, given by the end user - corresponding to one GAE request, I need roughly all the elevation of the surroundings within 1 to 200 kilometers. Some computation is done with all this data and a chart is return to the end user. I hope I made myself clear enough to understand the user case.

Answer (score 2):

OK, when working with google app engine and google cloud store, your are bound to several time constraints :

- 30s to read a file on GS.
- 10s when using GAE URLFetch service
- 60s for every request on GAE.

There is no way I can work around those limits in my particular situation.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, are those limits specified anywhere? It sucks because I was trying to save memory by writing a large file chunks at the time over the limit of a task queue (10 minutes), and I can't do that it seems